# Issues while trying to make a React Design System using Material UI components with Turborepo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, turborepo

I have cloned the [Turborepo Design System Starter](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/design-system) repo and ran

```
yarn workspace @acme/core add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --dev
```

I have added a simple re-export of a Material UI component in `acme-core/src`  e.g.

```js
// Button.tsx

export { default as Button, type ButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';
```

Then, I updated the `acme-core/src/index.tsx` to export the Button component

```js
export { Button, type ButtonProps } from './Button';
```

After I ran the library with `yarn dev` I get the following warning in my console when I open Storybook.

```
emotion-react.browser.esm.js:398 You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running multiple instances may cause problems. This can happen if multiple versions are used, or if multiple builds of the same version are used.
```

I create a new ViteJS React project and linked with `yarn link` while inside `packages/acme-core` and ran `yarn link @acme/core` in the project's root.

I have imported the Button component successfully with no TypeScript errors.

```js
import { Button } from '@acme/core';
```

The app breaks and the following error appears in my console.

```
index.mjs:12 Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "react" is not supported
    at index.mjs:12:9
    at ../../node_modules/@emotion/styled/dist/emotion-styled.cjs.dev.js (index.mjs:5938:5)
    at __require2 (index.mjs:18:49)
    at ../../node_modules/@emotion/styled/dist/emotion-styled.cjs.js (index.mjs:6097:24)
    at __require2 (index.mjs:18:49)
    at index.mjs:6555:29
```

I have tried updating `acme-core/src/Button.tsx` to include `React` in the scope with no luck.

```js
import React from 'react';

import MuiButton, { type ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';

export type ButtonProps = MuiButtonProps;

export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  return <MuiButton {...props} />;
}
```